# Font Color in a shaded box

Tags: html

Could you please tell me how to change the font color in this piece of code please?

```html
<div style="background-color: #fff8c6; width: 250px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 20px; padding: 8px;"><b>What you get with your phone:</b>
  <br />• Mains Charger
  <br />• USB Cable
  <br />• Instructions
  <br />• Box
  <br />• Guarantee
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change font color by adding e.g. `style="color: red;"`

```
<div style="background-color: #fff8c6; color: red; width: 250px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 20px; padding: 8px;">
    <b>What you get with your phone:</b><br /> 
    • Mains Charger<br /> • USB Cable<br /> • Instructions<br /> • Box<br /> • Guarantee
</div>
```

I prefer making lists using `<ul>` and `<li>` tags, too. Have a look at [this tutorial about HTML lists](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) And [example I wrote in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c115d0qs/) based on your code.

Comment: if you explain it, you would get upvotes, now the OP doesnt know what you changed

Answer (score 0):

Use: `color:red`

```
<div style="background-color: #fff8c6; width: 250px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 20px; padding: 8px;color:red;"><b>What you get with your phone:</b>
    <br />• Mains Charger
    <br />• USB Cable
    <br />• Instructions
    <br />• Box
    <br />• Guarantee
</div>
```

Avoid inline styles. Same can be done using css rules:

**CSS:**

```
div {
    color:red;
    background-color: #fff8c6;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <b>What you get with your phone:</b>
    <br />• Mains Charger
    <br />• USB Cable
    <br />• Instructions
    <br />• Box
    <br />• Guarantee
</div>
```